# Restriction so only the relevant uploader can download their files

Tags: php, codeigniter

im building a small website that allows users to upload and download their personal files from a server. Codeigniter is being used for the project and im using the [file uploading class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) to upload the files.

the problem that is arrised is how do i make sure that only the person who has uploaded the file can download it. currently all the files are uploaded to `localhost/curious/uploads`. although the files are visible only for the person who uploads, if they share the upload link anyone can download the file.

so if Steve uploads a file called `secure_rom.doc` and the path is `localhost/curious/uploads/secure_rom.doc` that file can be downloaded by anyone who has that link.

how is it possible make sure only the uploader can download from the download area and not anyone else?

Comment: Without knowing too much about your situation, probably the easiest way would be to have subfolders inside /uploads, named with the user's username, so /uploads/LiveEn will only be accessed by LiveEn, and /uploads/emma.fn2 can only be accessed by emma.fn2.

Comment: @emma.fn2 i did try that but the restriction doesn't work properly. so when they login only the user has access to the folder but if someone shares the link they can download id directly.

Comment: Were you doing any checks to see if the person trying to connect was logged in to your site, and had permission to download? If not, what you should do is setup a rewriterule which will match /uploads/username/file.xyz, and pass that to a download controller file, which will check $_SESSION['username'] for example, and compare that against the folder name (which will come from the URL). Just make sure to put the files outside of the visible web directory so they can't be downloaded right from the URL. That's probably why it wasn't working. If that makes any sense!? Sorry if it doesn't lol.

Comment: @emma.fn2 the system checks if the user is logged in or not, if success its redirected to the download section. so when the user trys to download i check the username against the folder. so if incorrect user, gives a permission denied. But the issue is direct link is shared `http://loacalhost/uploads/username/thefile.txt` anyone can download. I better check if anything can be done using the htaccess.

Comment: If you make sure that the files are outside of the web root directory, you shouldn't get any issues with being able to access the file directly. You'd then put some rewriterules in your htaccess which pass the URL to a script, which checks if the user can download it (based on the directory name).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a download script (try to adapt with codeigniter)

1) Check if the user is logged

2) Set the header with the file name and the content type

3) Read the file and send it to the client !

Controller :

```
if($userConnected) {
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file_name);
 header('Content-type: ' . $file_mime);
 $file_content = file_get_contents($file_location);
 echo $file_content;
}
else 
 echo 'No permission !';
```

[Mime content function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

Comment: a small clarification. when it prompts the user download will it show the direct link?

Comment: The direct link will never be shown cause you read the file by the server. The user will only see the name of the file. 

(You have to use GET paramater or something to retrieve your file, for example www.ex.com/script.php?file=secure_rom.doc, and on your server , you do file_get_contents('/curious/uploads/'.$_GET['file']))

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Way**

```
-just store the 'id' of the user when he/she uploaded something.
- hide the URL if 'user_id' is different.
- adding random character will have in securing.
```